# Bibliography with NATBIB - How to include only one class of references?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using LaTeX with Gummi on Linux. I create the bibliographies using the package Natbib. Is it possible to tell LaTeX to include only one precise class of references (e.g. article or book) when I call the command `\bibliography` at the end of my document. My goal is split the general bibliography in different sections and to call the command `\bibliography` in each section.

Comment: Hi and welcome, i don't know if this is possible with old system of `natbib` and bibtex, but it surely is with the modern combo of `biblatex` and `biber`.